# Reading from stdout and get a character string

Tags: c, stdout

I'd like to apologize for my poor english, for it is not my native language

So, here's my question. Is there any way, in C language,  to read from my stdout, and to turn whatever I read into a `*char` ? I can only use functions read, write, malloc and free.

My actual code looks like this

```
char* acquire_shape()
{
    char *buffer[BUF_SIZE + 1];
    int ret;

    ret = read(0, buffer, BUF_SIZE)
    buffer[ret] = '\0';
    return *buffer;
}
```

but I can't get it into a character string.

Comment: That's not a character string; Its a pointer array. Normally you would use `char buffer[BUF_SIZE+1];` though it looks like you need a dynamic allocation since you're returning this from *somewhere*. And hard-coding your descriptors? Bad idea.

Comment: I didn't get that part on hard-coding descriptors. What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Note, you need to release the memory allocated with `malloc` at some point using `free`:

```
char* acquire_shape(int fd) {
    char *buffer = malloc(BUF_SIZE + 1);
    int ret;

    if (buffer == NULL)
      return NULL;

    ret = read(fd, buffer, BUF_SIZE);
    buffer[ret] = '\0';
    return buffer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`char buffer[BUF_SIZE + 1];` is what you almost mean... except you cannot return it correctly since it's a pointer to local storage (which is undefined after the function returns). Your best bet is to change your function to something like this:

```
char* acquire_shape(char *buffer)
{
    int ret;

    ret = read(0, buffer, BUF_SIZE)
    buffer[ret] = '\0';
    return *buffer;
}
```

and call it like this:

```
    char mybuffer[BUF_SIZE + 1];
    acquire_shape(mybyffer);
```

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of char `*buffer[BUF_SIZE + 1];` is not a pointer to type char, but rather a pointer to a pointer of type char.  If you want to create a pointer to char you will need to allocate memory for your buffer:

```
char *buf = (char *) malloc(BUFSIZE + 1);

if (buf == NULL)
    return NULL;
```

You can then use the variable `buf` exactly how you used your `buffer` variable in your code sample.

Comment: Don't cast the result of `malloc`. It is needed in C++, but in C is [considered bad practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).